# Get specified properties of a model all at once in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass some user data to a view so it can be displayed in the profile page. There is quite a lot of it but I don't want to just pass everything, because there are some things the view shouldn't have access to. So my code looks like this:

```
return view('profile', [
    'username' => Auth::user()->username,
    'email' => Auth::user()->email,
    'firstname' => Auth::user()->firstname,
    'country' => Auth::user()->country,
    'city' => Auth::user()->city->name,
    'sex' => Auth::user()->sex,
    'orientation' => Auth::user()->orientation,
    'age' => Auth::user()->age,
    'children' => Auth::user()->children,
    'drinking' => Auth::user()->drinking,
    'smoking' => Auth::user()->smoking,
    'living' => Auth::user()->living,
    'about' => Auth::user()->about,
]);
```

My question is: Can this be written shorter/simpler?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

I don't want this: `{{ Auth::user()->firstname }}` because there is a logic in a view, which is bad - I think, there should be just plain variables to be displayed, in view, not anything else.

So I'm looking for something like:

```
return view('profile', Auth::user()->only(['firstname', 'email', ...]));
```

Comment: Can you not just pass in the user... e.g. return view('profile', ['user' => Auth::user()]) and then in your view do {{ $user->usernmae }} it's generally a cleaner way to pass a whole object over defining each field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create by yourself a method named like `getPublicData` and then return all those properties you need.

```
...
public function getPublicData() {
    return [
        'property_name' => $this->property_name
    ];
}
...
```

... and then use it in your controller/views. Maybe it's not an optimal solution, but you can isolate this thing in the model and avoid too much code in the controller.

Another advanced approach could be the override of the `__get` method. However, [I am not the first in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170121/laravel-eloquent-model-attribute-visibility).

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's what I was thinking about from the beginning. Just asked if there isn't something built-in I didn't knew. Apparently, there isn't. So thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to pass these variable to the view, you can directly access them in the view using blade

```
<h1>{{ Auth::user()->username }}</h1>
```